# Change css of placeholder text of md-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I use Angular Material version 1.1

I want to change the style of placeholder text of md-autocomplete component. However, i could not select the placeholder as an apart element to play with its styling.

Here you see a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPBOXr) to illustrate the problem.

I tried the following dictating codes but they did not work

```
md-autocomplete{
  color: red !important;
}
md-autocomplete-wrap{
  color: red !important;
}
input{
  color: red !important;
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: [`::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/)

Comment: would it work in all browsers? and would it be valid for all input fields?

Comment: Go through the reference..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the placeholders within an element, the pseudo element `placeholder` should be user.

In this case:

```
md-autocomplete input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:red;
}
md-autocomplete input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color:red;
}

md-autocomplete input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color:red;
}

md-autocomplete input:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    color:red;
}
```

[How to change](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/)

[Pseudo elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

Thanks to @Rayon Dabre:

Answer (score 0):

You can use following selector to style the [placeholder] for different browser.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: blue;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: blue;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: blue;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: blue;  
}
```

Example on CodePen : http://codepen.io/bigbrov/pen/LNzbqp